# Regex to include strings that start with @ but not in the middle of string?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match @username similar to twitter.   The regex I'm using right now:   **"([@])(\S+)"** works decently well for this.

However limitations are as follows
test@test.com matches test.com

Now I want to completly exclude test@test.com

However, some of my users have usernames test@test.com and want to include them if they actually have an @ in front of that email username.

So @test@test.com should match

**Summary:
Needs to match:**

@username

@test

@test@test.com

**Do not want to match:**

test@test.com

Comment: `\s([@])(\S+)` just check for a space in front of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using a negative lookbehind, eg:

```
(?<!\S)@(\S+)
```

This will not include any possible space before the `@foo`, so you can replace it without issue.

Comment: Brilliant, for some reason I didn't think of a negative lookbehind. Though to keep the subset matches he currently has, I would suggest `(?<!\S)(@)(\S+)`

Comment: Qtax, not sure if you are still watching this thread, but first thanks so much for the 99% working answer.  Found a weird situation where it doesnt work as best as it could.  If the string is @username<br /> then it matches part of the <br as well, could this be modified to exclude the character return?   Thanks again!!

Comment: @Mark, try to instead of `\S` use `[^\s<>]`, eg: `(?<![^\s<>])@([^\s<>]+)`.

Comment: @qtax yes perfect.  Wish I could upvote more.  Thanks again for the amazing help!!

Answer (score 1):

Making as an answer, you don't want to check for `@` in middle of the text, but it needs a space in front, so use `(\s|^)+([@])(\S+)`

Comment: `(\s|^)+([@])(\S+)` will match either a space in front, or if the line begins with the `@`

Comment: So it would have to be at the beginning of the string?  Sure, that can be done with `^([@])(\S+)` ^^

Comment: The (\s|^)+([@])(\S+) matches perfectly as asked, problem is by including the space, I run a preg_replace on it and its now adding my replacement without spaces into the sentence.  Was wondering if there was a possible fix in the regex without having to manuallly adding spaces.  The original ([@])(\S+) matches just the word and no spaces so it doesnt disrupt the sentance structure

Comment: You can use the reference to it, something like `$1<mylink, etc>$3`? (in the replacement part)

Comment: @Mark (Without making it a subset, we can't assert either the beginning or a white space, and the subset will only match the last character, so we need to reference it within the replacement in order to match one or the other.)  If not, you can use two `preg_replace` statements, one with `^([@])(\S+)`, the other with `\s([@])(\S+)` in order to match inline and starting ones.

Comment: @Mark, use a lookbehind. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The regex would look something like this: `^@.*` The ^ will anchor you to the start of the line or the string.  Be sure to check out [OverAPI Regex](http://overapi.com/regex/), their cheat sheets are very nice.

Answer (score 0):

^@.*
The above regular expression matches what you are looking for